# How to show different dash boards for different users

Tags: angular

I am working with angular 7.
How to show different dashboards to different users like site admin user, org admin user, normal user, super admin user.

i would like to use Role Guard for this instead of child routes and dynamic routing.
kindly let me know how to do it.

Comment: Are all dashboards separate components? If so, check the role when the user login and route the corresponding component.

Comment: [Check this example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/22/angular-7-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example)  -- Your request is too wide for an answer.

Comment: only for the dashboard page or for different pages for different logins?

Comment: @Arcteezy all dashboards are separate components.

Comment: @sibabratswain only for dashboard page

Comment: @Santhosh Then by default route to a component (normal user dashboard since that will be used most). From there check user role and if it's not a normal user, redirect to corresponding component. Or else you can check the user role in a route guard and redirect from there itself.

Comment: then you must have different components for different logins then you can redirect it as per the roles after getting logged in. Else keep a usetypeFlag and update it as per the user type and show using `*ngif`

Answer (score 1):

If you have different components for different logins then you can redirect it as per the roles after getting logged in. Else keep a **usetypeFlag** and update it as per the user type and show using `*ngif`.

You can make userTypeFlag a **BehaviorSubject** and update it which will be more dynamic and value can be changed from anywhere and reflect dynamically in your HTML page.

```
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
private $roleType: BehaviorSubject<any>;

 setRole(role: any) {
 this.$roleType.next(role);
 }

 getRole(): Observable<any> {
    return this.$roleType.asObservable();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create different component for all user than first check which user is login than set *ngIf related to user.
And if you don't create different component than set *ngIf in your html componenet related to which user is login.